# PL/pgSQL rows to json array

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I'm trying to retrieve a json array containing the rows returned with this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_users_list() 
RETURNS TABLE (
id INTEGER,
name VARCHAR,
surname VARCHAR,
fkrole INTEGER,
username VARCHAR
) as $$
BEGIN

RETURN QUERY SELECT users.id, users.name,
                    users.surname, users.fkrole, 
                    users.username 
FROM users;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Can anyone give me a hint? How can I convert multiple rows into a single JSON array?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
SELECT JSON_AGG(src) AS my_json_array
FROM (
  SELECT 
    users.id, 
    users.name, 
    users.surname, 
    users.fkrole, 
    users.username 
  FROM users
) src
;
```

This will give you all the rows from your "src" query returned as a single json array.

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/6241a/2

Here's some more info on the Postgres JSON functions: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-json.html

Comment: Thanks for the hint! For future references the working fuction is `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_users_list() 
RETURNS JSON as $$
DECLARE
 users JSON;
BEGIN
 SELECT json_agg(src) INTO users
 FROM (
 SELECT users.id, users.name,
        users.surname, roles.role, 
        users.username 
  FROM users, roles
  WHERE users.fkrole = roles.id
 ) src
 ; 
 RETURN users;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;`

Comment: My pleasure. :)

Comment: You saved my time a lot. thank you so very much.

Comment: You got it my friend :)